# Can I use a custom node_modules path with create-react-app

Tags: node.js, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I'm working on a project inside a VM (really docker on windows via vscode remote-containers). I would like to avoid building my react app at `$(pwd)/node_modules`, because everything under `$(pwd)` is synced to my windows file system which causes serious performance issues.

I'm fairly new to nodejs in general, but I'm surprised how difficult this seems to figure out.

I successfully started with this:

- `yarn --modules-folder /tmp/vendor`

This gave me a `/tmp/vendor` folder with expected dependencies listed.

For the next step, I want to run the development server, so I run this:

- `yarn --modules-folder /tmp/vendor start`

I get `/bin/sh: react-scripts: command not found`. I figure `yarn`s `--modules-folder` doesn't reconfigure PATH information when running commands (`yarn start` calls `react-scripts start`). So I just added my own PATH as a workaround:

- `PATH=$PATH:/tmp/vendor/.bin/ yarn --modules-folder /tmp/vendor start`

But now I get this:

```
[root@352b76226b83 owio]# PATH=$PATH:/tmp/vendor/.bin/ yarn --modules-folder /tmp/vendor start
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-scripts start
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:965
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'react-dev-utils/crossSpawn'
Require stack:
- /tmp/vendor/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:962:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:838:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/vendor/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js:18:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/tmp/vendor/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js' ]
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command
```

Since it is complaining about missing modules, I also set the NODE_PATH (I guess yarn doesn't forward this variable either):

- `NODE_PATH=/tmp/vendor PATH=$PATH:/tmp/vendor/.bin/ yarn --modules-folder /tmp/vendor start`

With this, I get:

```
./src/index.jsx
Line 0:  Parsing error: Cannot find module 'eslint-scope' from '/tmp/vendor/eslint/lib/api.js'
```

I'm stuck here, because `eslint-scope` *does* exist, and I've already what I can to work around path problems.

I'm half tempted to start trying other tools outside of CRA and yarn but I don't really know the ecosystem well enough yet to understand how to port my application over. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I've gotten closer by changing `vendor` to `node_modules`. I guess this convention is somehow necessary. I also added `NODE_PATH=/tmp/node_modules` to a `.env` file, and the `--modules-folder /tmp/node_modules` to a `.yarnrc` file.

EDIT 2:

I made a symlink for `$(pwd)/node_modules -> /tmp/node_modules` as suggested and this seems to have worked this time around, given that I added the NODE_PATH to `.env`.

It seems all the react-script stuff is working now, but when compiling the local source files under `src/components/`, I get errors about not resolving modules from `/tmp/node_modules` that do indeed exist.

Comment: What about a link to custom folder? Does it cause problems too?

Comment: Just added an `EDIT 2`. I tried this earlier and had issues, but I'm seeing a new error this time around with the sym link.

Comment: Oh hold on, I made the wrong link from my earlier naming convention.

Comment: Seems to have taken this time around, thanks. I think I tried this earlier without having `NODE_PATH` set in `.env` and it had issues. Maybe I'll narrow down exactly what I need and don't need and post follow up answer.

Answer (score 2):

After some tinkering and support from Estus, I found that having the following things works for me:

- `.env` file with `NODE_PATH=/tmp/node_modules`
- `.yarnrc` file with `--modules-folder /tmp/node_modules`
- symlink for `$(pwd)/node_modules -> /tmp/node_modules`

I'm not sure why the symlink is necessary, and would love to know if anyone has a `.env` like solution. It seems my local source files are compiled against this folder regardless of having `NODE_PATH` set.

Other oddities I don't understand, but maybe someone will:

- I could not *just* have `NODE_PATH` as a variable in my `yarn` command. It seems having the value in `.env` changed how modules within `node_modules` were compiled.
- I could not use a name other than `node_modules`. No idea why.

As an aside:

For anyone landing here having the same issue (slow docker performance on windows or mac), you may need to make sure you're editor is not indexing node_modules. For example, I have set `files.watcherExclude` in my `.vscode/settings.json` to include `"**/node_modules": true,"`.